# Как вывести данные за квартал в зависимости от заданной даты?

Tags: sql, oracle, дата

Допустим в `а` , мы, в зависимости от полученной даты, выводим данные и в `b` выводим количество количество этих данных по месяцам.

```
with a as
(
  select *
   from table_1 t1
    where trunc(t1, 'Q') = trunc(:add_data, 'Q')  -- Полученная дата
),
b as
(
  select table_id
  , (select count(*)
      from a
       where t2.table_id = a.table_id) january -- Разбивка по месяцам
  , (select count(*)
      from a
       where t2.table_id = a.table_id) february -- Разбивка по месяцам
  , (select count(*)
      from a
       where t2.table_id = a.table_id) march  -- Разбивка по месяцам
        ...
  from table_2 t2
```

Как в запросе можно вывести только месяцы, которые относяться к определённому кварталу в зависимости от искомой даты?

Например:

```
trunc(to_date('01.02.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),'Q')

          1 кв  

декабрь   январь   февраль
```

Comment: Akina, по идее я уже получаю номер квартала тут - trunc(t1, 'Q') = trunc(:add_data, 'Q'). У меня затык в том как вывести данные по тем месяцам которые относяться к данному кварталу.

Comment: *как вывести данные по тем месяцам которые относяться к данному кварталу* Обратная операция. Умножить номер квартала на 3, отнять 2, 1 и 0 - вот тебе номера месяцев этого квартала.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по последней правке ТС, ожидается результат с транспонированием строк в столбцы.

Это можно достичь функцией `PIVOT`, но ввести только дату недостаточно, имена месяцев, соответствующие этой дате, должны быть сформированы заране *до парсинга* запроса SQL интерпретатором. Другими словами, на чистом SQL и одним запросом задачу решить нельзя.

Вот пример на PL/SQL. Часть с формированием имён столбцов (`FOR...LOOP`),  может быть аналогично аналогично реализована на любом языке в клиенте при формировании полного запроса.

```
var rc refcursor
declare 
    qmon date := trunc (date'2021-02-01', 'q');
    cols varchar2 (96);
    mons varchar2 (16);
begin
    for i in 1..3 loop
        mons := rtrim (to_char (add_months (qmon, (i-1)), 'Month'));
        cols := cols||''''||mons||''' "'||mons||'",';
    end loop;
    cols := rtrim (cols, ',');
    open :rcdata for q'[
        select * 
        from (
            select trim (to_char (dt, 'Month')) mon
            from t1 where :qmon=trunc (dt, 'q')) 
        pivot (count (*) for mon in (]'||cols||'))' using qmon;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
   January   February      March
---------- ---------- ----------
        31         28         31
```

Answer (score 3):

> как в селекте можно вывести только месяцы, которые относяться к определённому кварталу в зависимости от искомой даты

Вот так, искоммая дата `2021-02-01`, это первый квартал с 3 первыми месяцами года:

```
create table t1 (id, dt) as
    select rownum, date'2021-01-01'+rownum-1 
    from dual connect by level<=365
/

with a as (
    select trunc (dt, 'mm') mm
    from t1
    where trunc (dt, 'Q') = trunc (date'2021-02-01', 'Q')
)
select count (*) total, to_char (mm, 'Month') mon
from a
group by mm
order by mm
/
```

Результат:

```
     TOTAL MON                                 
---------- ------------------------------------
        31 March                               
        31 January                             
        28 February
```