# Ошибка при создании piplined функции: PLS-00321: expression <data type> is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

Tags: функции, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица, которая содержит следующий пример данные:

```
with t as (
select 123456 DRAW_KEY, 1 WINCAT_NUM,0 WIN_AMOUNT,0 WIN_COUNT
from dual
union all
select 123456 DRAW_KEY, 2 WINCAT_NUM,0 WIN_AMOUNT,0 WIN_COUNT
from dual
union all
select 123456 DRAW_KEY, 3 WINCAT_NUM,0 WIN_AMOUNT,0 WIN_COUNT
from dual
union all
select 123456 DRAW_KEY, 4 WINCAT_NUM,30000 WIN_AMOUNT,12 WIN_COUNT
from dual
union all
select 123456 DRAW_KEY, 5 WINCAT_NUM,6000 WIN_AMOUNT,73 WIN_COUNT
from dual
) select * from t
```

На основе этих данных создаю `piplined` функциию:

```
CREATE TYPE l_result AS OBJECT (
  DRAW_KEY number,
  WINCAT_NUM  number,
  WIN_AMOUNT number,
  WIN_COUNT number);
/
CREATE TYPE table_pip IS TABLE OF l_result;

CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction1(v_draw_key in number) RETURN table_pip Pipelined IS
  v_query clob;
  v_cols clob;
BEGIN
  select listagg(wincat_num ,', ') within group (order by wincat_num)
  into v_cols
  from customers1
  where draw_key = 123456; --v_draw_key!
  v_query := 'SELECT * FROM (
    select draw_key,wincat_num,win_amount,win_count
    from customers1
    where draw_key = 123456) PIVOT (
      sum(win_count) as win_count,sum(win_amount) as win_amount
      FOR wincat_num IN ('||v_cols||'))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query into l_result;
  pipe row(l_result);
END;
```

Но выдает ошибки:

> PLS-00321: expression 'L_RESULT' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

и

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'L_RESULT'.

Что я написал не так, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: А зачем вам конвеерная ф-я, если у вас в результате только одна запись? Если это только пример, то он довольно неудачный.

Comment: Плюс за тестовые данные текстом в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина:  `pipe row(l_result);`, здесь ожидается сущность объекта, а не сам объектный тип.

Посмотрите, как это работает на [воспроизводимом примере](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=603ae2cbbe2e4b10c3f36c60dce7b559) с данными из вопроса:

```
create type resultRow as object (
    draw_key number, wincat_num  number, win_amount number, win_count number)
/
create type resultRows is table of resultRow
/
create or replace function pipefunc (draw_key in number) return resultRows pipelined is
begin
    for r in (
        select * 
        from customers1 
        where draw_key = pipefunc.draw_key
    ) loop
        pipe row (resultRow (r.draw_key, r.wincat_num, r.win_amount, r.win_count));
    end loop;
    return;
end;
/
```

Вызов и результат:

```
select * from pipefunc (123456)
/

  DRAW_KEY WINCAT_NUM WIN_AMOUNT  WIN_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    123456          1          0          0
    123456          2          0          0
    123456          3          0          0
    123456          4      30000         12
    123456          5       6000         73
```

---

PS
Динамический запрос внутри функции, в этом ответе не расматривается, так как не относится к вопросу. Посмотрите схожую тему [транспонирование с динамическим кол-вом столбцов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1263128).

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснение.
А можете , пожалуйста, подсказать, как мне корректно объявить L_RESULT, чтобы я мог через нее выводить n-кол-во столбцов? Или в данном скрипте это невозможно в принцнипе сделать и нужно пробовать что-то другое?

Comment: В данной функции - невозможно. Если версия 18c и старше, то можно с [PTF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-981102A8-5204-4931-B10A-93486304B184). Задайте новый вопрос, если при реализации возникнут трудности. PS Не забудте отметить этот ответ как принятый (галочка слева от ответа), если он вам  оказался полезным.

Comment: Да, если версия <18, то можно обьявить несколько типов, но n-кол-во столбцов должно быть заранее предсказуемым, например: 3, 6, 12 месяцев, итд., но это скорее всего не то, что вы ищете.

Comment: И ещё, чуть не забыл, для версий <18, делаете функцию, которая возвращает курсор. У курсора кол-во столбцов определяется на этапе компиляции. Это то, что вы ищете.

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарии. Изначально все и делалось с помощью курсора, но проблема в том, что мне нужно будет делать join к таблице данной функции, а селект из курсора сделать не получится,тк точно не известно кол-во столбцов и данных, может не хватить памяти

Comment: Рад был помочь! Пробуйте, если что-то не получится, то задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Вот нашёл [пример траснпонирования с динамическим кол-вом столбцов](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HPN95108FSSZD87PXX7MG3LW3.html). Это как раз то, что вы пытались сделать.